# Eclipse PDT: How to add 'Javascript' as an option to the PHP explorer New... popup menu?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I'm not creating a plug-in, just using the application.

I want the right click pop-up menu in the PHP Explorer pane to have 'Javascript Source File' as one of its default 'New' options (along with the usual Task, PHP File, Folder, etc.)

I realise I can get to it by going into the New...Other... option and selecting from the tree-view but as I write a lot of Javascript it would be useful to have it in the immediate list.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're able to customize IDE. Select menu Window->Customize Perspective, move 'Menu Visibility' tab, expand 'File' and 'New', check 'JavaScript Source File'.